# Zsh zle function segfaults on `trap 'zle reset-prompt' EXIT`

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, segmentation-fault

I have the following function to select a tmux session with fzf:

```sh
function tmx {
    [ -n "$ZLE_STATE" ] && trap 'zle reset-prompt' EXIT
    local tmux item
    tmux="$(which tmux)" || return $?
    if [ -z "$1" ] ; then
        # The 1st value is the query string.
        # The 2nd value is the selected, matched value, or empty if none.
        $tmux list-sessions -F '#{session_name}' |\
            fzf --header jump-to-session --print-query \
                --preview "$tmux capture-pane -ept {}" |\
            while read ; do  # Pick the last non-empty value.
                [ -n "$REPLY" ] && item="$REPLY"
            done
    else
        item="$1"
    fi
    [ -z "$item" ] && return 1
    (
        # Restore the standard std* file descriptors for tmux.
        # https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512979/22339
        exec </dev/tty; exec <&1;
        if [ -z "$TMUX" ] ; then
            $tmux new-session -As "$item"
        else
            $tmux has-session -t "$item" || \
                $tmux new-session -ds "$item"
            $tmux switch-client -t "$item"
        fi
    )
}
zle -N tmx
bindkey "$(tput kf4)" tmx
```

When invoking the function as a ZLE widget that activates the `trap ... EXIT`, it often crashes with `Segmentation fault` once I detach from a selected tmux session, or when I abort fzf with Ctrl-C.

It seems that the culprit is `trap 'zle reset-prompt' EXIT`. When I comment out this line, it works fine. Is this a (known) ZSH bug? Or am I missing something important?

---

**Workaround:** This seems to work around the problem:

```bash
function tmx {
    {
      # function body up to `exec` ...
    } always {
      zle reset-prompt
    }
    (
      exec # ...
      # ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Do you know a reliable way how to reproduce the crash? What versions are you using? With mine (zsh-5.9-0-g73d3173, fzf 0.42.0; only maybe relevant: tmux 3.3_a-7, rxvt-unicode 9.31) and your original code, I wasn't able to get a crash.

Comment: I only experienced it with **zsh 5.8**. I'll try to construct a minimal, reproducing example and get back to you. Thanks!